# Figuring out convenient footprint for given actual lead spacings

Tags: pcb-design

This a beginner question, but I couldn't find an answer in net. I want to place the following components call it from left to right Cap1, Cap2 and Res on a PCB:

[image]

As you see above I also mentioned the lead to lead spaces in mm.

So to associate footprints in PCB designer such as Altium I convert these spacing lengths to inch which becomes for 5, 6 and 12mm as: 0.19685, 0.23622 and 0.472441 inch in order.

But in the designer software the options for the caps are RAD-0.1, RAD-0.2, RAD-0.3, RAD-0.4 and the options for the resistors are AXIAL-0.1, AXIAL-0.2, AXIAL-0.3 and AXIAL-0.4.

Which footprints are convenient to use in my case for the Cap1, Cap2 and Res?

Answer (score 1):

**Learn to make your own footprints**. Get a pair of digital calipers for cases when you don't have a datasheet available. Check and double-check the lead diameter vs. footprint on through-hole components before releasing the design to be fabricated. By the time you check the canned footprints you can make one of your own that matches the actual dimensions and height (and perhaps has a 3D model attached if you're into that kind of thing).

For axial lead 1/4-W resistors that you bend yourself, either 10mm or 0.4" is fine.
The AXIAL0.4 footprint has 62mil diameter pads, 32 mil holes and (obviously?) 400mil pin spacing.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Altium, only Kicad. For 1/4W resistors a common choice is 0.3 inch or 7.62mm. For the capacitors you show, 0.2 inch would be a close choice. Footprints can be edited in Kicad, or alternate footprints can be specified (if e.g. a longer footprint is desired for jumping tracks etc.). I'm sure this can also be done in Altium (although I don't know how). Make sure the capacitor lead spacing is measured near the actual device, not at the end which will be cut off after soldering. The distance is between centers of the wires, so average of the inner spacing and outer spacing.

From a search on the net, people seem to be using axial-0.3 or axial-0.4 for resistors.